# S3 file upload from PHP error: "Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\hash_init()"

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am attempting to upload a file to an S3 bucket via PHP. This has been working in the past and I believe it is now not working due to PHP versioning, but unsure. I have the GuzzleHTTP and AWS subfolders. I now receive the following error: GuzzleHttp/Psr7/functions.php, errline: 417, errstr: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\hash_init().

I did find that there were some changes to hash_init in 7.2, so I rolled back to 7.1 and still got the error.

```
<?php

    require 'aws-autoloader.php';

    use Aws\S3\S3Client;
    use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

    function image_to_s3($fileName) {


        // Connect to AWS
        try {
            // You may need to change the region. It will say in the URL when the bucket is open
            // and on creation.
            $s3 = S3Client::factory(
                array(
                    'credentials' => array(
                        'key' => 'KEY',
                        'secret' => 'SECRET'
                    ),
                    'version' => 'latest',
                    'region'  => 'us-east-2'
                )
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // We use a die, so if this fails. It stops here. Typically this is a REST call so this would
            // return a json object.
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        // prep the aws s3 bucket
        $bucket = 'BUCKETNAME';
        $keyname = $fileName;
        $filepath = 'SUBDIRECTORY/' . $fileName;

        echo $filePath;

        try {

            // Upload a file.
            $result = $s3->putObject(array(
                'Bucket'       => $bucket,
                'Key'          => $keyname,
                'SourceFile'   => $filepath,
                'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
                'ACL'          => 'public-read',
                'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
                'Metadata'     => array(    
                    'param1' => 'value 1',
                    'param2' => 'value 2'
                )
            ));

        } catch (S3Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }

        return '';

    }

?>
```

Full stack trace...

```
Fatal error: errno: 1, errfile: \/home\/USERNAME\/GuzzleHttp\/Psr7\/functions.php, errline: 417, errstr: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\hash_init() in \/home\/USERNAME\/GuzzleHttp\/Psr7\/functions.php:417\nStack trace:\n#0 \/home\/USERNAME\/Aws\/Signature\/SignatureV4.php(164): GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\hash(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\LazyOpenStream), 'sha256')\n#1 \/home\/USERNAME\/Aws\/Signature\/S3SignatureV4.php(22): Aws\\Signature\\SignatureV4->getPayload(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request))\n#2 \/home\/USERNAME\/Aws\/Middleware.php(126): Aws\\Signature\\S3SignatureV4->signRequest(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Request), Object(Aws\\Credentials\\Credentials))\n#3 \/home\/USERNAME\/GuzzleHttp\/Promise\/FulfilledPromise.php(39): Aws\\Middleware::Aws\\{closure}(Object(Aws\\Credentials\\Credentials))\n#4 \/home\/USERNAME\/GuzzleHttp\/Promise\/TaskQueue.php(47): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\FulfilledPromise::GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\{closure}()\n#5 \/home\/USERNAME\/GuzzleHttp\/Promise\/Promise.php(246): GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\TaskQueue->run("}
```

Comment: Are you sure the hash extension is enabled? It can be explicitly disabled when the package is built. `phpinfo();` should tell you that.

Comment: This is the only line in phpinfo which seemed to relate, it is in the 2nd row 'Configure Command' ...--enable-hash=shared'...

Comment: In that case you have to explicitly install the hash extension. How do you that depends on which distribution or operating system you're using.

Comment: Does shared mean it is not installed?

Comment: Adding answer as comment due to lack of reputation: @MatsLindh led me down the correct path. Hash is built into PHP now, but my hosting provider for my test environment (DreamHost) set the enable-hash to shared which means each user needs to manually enable the extension by importing the Shared Object file. I did this by adding the following command to my php.ini file

```
extension = hash.so
```

You can tell as soon as the extension is loading correctly because you will have a whole new table added to phpinfo() for hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MatsLindh led me down the correct path. Hash is built into PHP now, but my hosting provider for my test environment (DreamHost) set the enable-hash to shared which means each user needs to manually enable the extension by importing the Shared Object file. I did this by adding the following command to my php.ini file `extension = hash.so` You can tell as soon as the extension is loading correctly because you will have a whole new table added to phpinfo() for hash.